# Open other app using bundle id in Android using React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking

Is it possible to open another app inside my app just using the bundle id of the app I need to open? If yes how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't open other app inside you app but can redirect to other app(third party app) like whatsapp,instagram or any other app

```
 const url = 'whatsapp://';

             Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported=> {
                if (!supported) {

                    console.log('Can\'t handle url: ' + url);

         }else{

                    return Linking.openURL(url);

        }

         }).catch(err =>
         console.error('An error occurred', err));
```